# Differential equation $y'(t) = -\Big(a+y(t+a)-y(t)\Big)_+$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to solve the following differential equation on $[0,T]$ (or on $[0,+\infty]$ if it makes sense):

$$y'(t) = -\Big(a+y(t+a)-y(t)\Big)_+,$$
where $a$ is a positive constant and $y(t) = 0$ for all $t\geq T$ (or $y(+\infty) =0$).

Answer (score 2):

This delay-differential equation is linear.

By inspection, a solution of the inhomogeneous equation is

$$y(t)=-\frac a{a+1}t.$$

Then with $y(t):=z(t)-\dfrac a{a+1}t$,

$$z'(t)+z(t+a)-z(t)=0.$$

We try $e^{bt}$, giving the compatibility condition

$$b+e^{ba}-1=0.$$

Finally,

$$y(t)=ce^{bt}-\frac a{a+1}t$$ where $b$ is the solution of the above condition.

I do not guarantee that these are the only solutions.

Comment: 1) How do we know that $(z(t+a)-z(t)+a/(a+1))$ is non negative (to get rid of the positive part)?
2) The compatibility condition yields $b=0$ right?

Comment: @pyth: right; I do not guarantee that these are the only solutions ;-)

Comment: Note that the equation $b + e^{ba} - 1 = 0$ has infinitely many complex solutions of the form $b = 1 - W(a e^a)/a$ where $W$ is a branch of the Lambert $W$ function.  In that case you can replace $e^{bt}$ by its real or imaginary part to get real solutions.

Comment: And of course you can take linear combinations of these.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thank  you for your comment, could you please elaborate?

Comment: For example, take $a=1$.   For the "$-1$" branch of Lambert W we get $b \approx 1.532092122 + 4.597158013 i$.  Thus one solution is $y(t) = {{\rm e}^{ 1.532092122\,t}}\cos \left(  4.597158013\,t \right) -{
\frac {t}{2}}$.  This has $y' > 0$ for approximately $--0.5599353773 < t < 0.04912688991$.

Answer (score 1):

Some points concerning the delayed differential equation.

Considering $t \ge  a$ and using the Laplace transform we have

$$
sY(s)+e^{-a s}Y(s) -Y(s) = y_0-a
$$

or

$$
Y(s) = \frac{y_0-a}{s+e^{-a s}-1}
$$

now looking at the poles for $Y(s)$ we have with $s = x + i y$

$$
s+e^{-a s}-1 = 0\Rightarrow \cases{x+e^{-a x}\cos(a y) - 1 = 0\\ y - e^{-a x}\sin(a y) = 0}
$$

Follows a plot showing at the intersections for blue and red paths, the pole locations, for $a = 1$. As we can observe, the behavior is rather complex. The pole locations depend on the $a$ values. From those considerations we can conclude also about stability. Note the existence of a double pole at the origin as well as infinite more inside the left complex semi-plane.

[image]